# Побитовые операции C++

Tags: битовые-операции, c, c++

Какая польза от побитовых операций на самом деле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В ряде случаев - существенно экономят память (ценой замедления операций), например, когда идет работа с массивами логических величин.
2. Естественны при обращениям к регистрам устройств, которые по своей архитектуре часто включают битовые поля.

Comment: исли можно, ещё кокой нибуть пример =)

Answer (score 6):

Польза немалая. Особенно при низкоуровневом программировании.

Например, логическое "или" используется для установки разных значимых битов при передачи параметров системным вызовам Unix. Есть такой замечательный вызов open, открывающий файл для чтения/записи. Его второй параметр - переменная типа int -  определяет режим доступа к нему - запись, чтение, создание, очистка и куча других. Каждый режим определяется одним битом. К примеру, чтобы открыть файл для записи, чтения, создания и очистки при открытии объединяем маски - 
  `O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`.

Вызов fcntl позволяет, в частности получить информацию о режиме доступа к открытому файлу:

```
int a = fcntl (fd, F_GETFL) ;
```

Возвращаемая переменная содержит установленные биты, соответствующие режимам открытия файла. Чтобы, например, получить информацию о том, установлен ли режим O_TRUNC, делаем

```
if (a & O_TRUNC) { 
    smth    
}
```

Операторы файлового сдвига << >> позволяют ускорить деление или умножение на степень двойки.

Битовые поля в ряде случаев помогают сэкономить память, что может быть полезно, к примеру, для встроенных устройств.

Это лишь часть примеров пользы от битовых операций. Конечно, есть масса и других случаев целесообразности их применения.

Answer (score 3):

1. [XOR-шифрование](http://axofiber.org.ru/inside/xor.ciphering.htm)
2. [Маска сети](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)
3. Опять таки экономия памяти:

Вместо выделения 8-ми байт для
   каких-то булевых значений можно
   использовать один байт + битовые
   операции.

Answer (score 2):

Чаще всего используются для указания флагов. Например, в WinAPI.

> ```
> CreateWindow( "STATIC", "Static Text",
>               WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, //побитовые операции
>               10, 10, 100, 15,
>               NULL,
>               NULL,
>               NULL, NULL );
> ```

Также широко используется в стандартной библиотеке. В общем там, где нужно ввести множественное числовое значение.